# Hadoop Hive SQL to pull data from a table with a reserved keyword name

Tags: hive, keyword, reserved

my table name is case
I am trying select * from .`case` in the beeline sql but it just won't work! Please advise. Thank you in advance

Comment: I have tried the `case` option (with the backtick sign on the tilde key on the keyboard) in select option but it won't work

Comment: What is the error message ? Hope you used select * from `database`.`case` ?